# Facebook allow access url and redirect for login

Tags: c#, facebook

HI,

How can I programatically login facebook. I have an application - i need a url for optaing the facebook login page. After that do i have to do a getResponse()? WHy? What do I have to do in order to obtain the token and have a correct allow in order to login?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an existing library like the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) (preferred) or the official [Facebook Developer Toolkit](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/). The official toolkit isn't updated all that often so you should use the C# SDK which is much more active.

Don't try to code it from scratch. Your asking for tons of problems if you do.

**Edit** Since I wasn't totally clear, I'll say that these frameworks handle the handshakes,  tokens, building the API requests and listening to the response all automatically. Don't try to handle it yourself. Someone else already did the hard work.